# Failed to resolve: firebaseui-android.internal:lintchecks:unspecified

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, firebaseui

I got message:

> Failed to resolve: firebaseui-android.internal:lintchecks:unspecified

when I add `implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.2.0'` on dependencies.

How to solve them?

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'

// Displaying images
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.2.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update**:  Fixed in release 3.2.1.

This problem was logged as a [FirebaseUI issue](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/1116) yesterday.  The recommended workaround is:

```
compile('com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.2.0') {
    exclude module: 'lintchecks'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had also the exact problem as you do, 2 hours ago and I fixed it by changing this line of code:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.2.0'
```

with

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.3'
```

See [here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android). The last version `3.2.0` did not work for me either.